# AsyncTask for showing dialog

Tags: android

How can i use AsyncTask Class to showing dialog when execute a task???

```
class TestAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ProgressDialog.show(???, null, null);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `TestAsyncTask` is an inner class to an `Activity`, then you can use the activity name `.this` to get the context.  If TestAsyncTask is not an inner class, then you will want to pass an instance of your `Activity` into the constructor so that you can provide it as the `Context` to the [`ProgressDialog.show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#show%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

Here is an example of the inner class method:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    //Activity Lifecycle methods

    class TestAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "title", "message");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //very long computation...
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
           dialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that you should save off the `ProgressDialog` to a instance variable in the `onPreExecute()` method and call `cancel()` on it in the `onPostExecute()` method.

The other approach looks similar:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    //Activity Lifecycle methods


}

class TestAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    MyActivity activity;        

    TaskAsynTask(MyActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "title", "message");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //very long computation...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}
```